# PayPal (Payflow Pro) Error 52

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I am trying to set up a test process to get some authorizations completed.  I managed to get a response other than Invalid Vendor (I had set up the account wrong), but now we get this response:

```
RESULT=52&PNREF=XXXXXXXXXXXX&RESPMSG=Insufficient permissions to perform transaction
```

Any thoughts on how to correct this?  Request string:

```
TRXTYPE[1]=A
&VERBOSITY[4]=HIGH
&ACCT[16]=411111XXXXXX1111
&TENDER[1]=C
&AMT[4]=1.99
&CURRENCY[3]=USD
&USER[8]=MyPayFlowUser
&VENDOR[8]=MyPayFlowUser
&PARTNER[6]=PayPal
&PWD[10]=XXXXXXXXXX
&ORIGID[13]=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have API_FULL_TRANSACTIONS. Result code 52 usually means you are trying to make a Payflow API call when you only have a Payflow Link account. Payflow Link accounts are only allowed to make an API call for the SECURETOKEN.

Comment: How can I find out whether I have a Payflow Link account or Payflow Pro?

Answer (score 0):

Without more details and looking at the account, it is hard to say what is happening.  If I had to guess just based on these details you provided, it sounds like you do not have permissions to perform the type of API call that you are trying to.  If you can provide the PNREF number for the transaction I can take a look at it on my end.